# AddRange() is not working when adding list items to a Collection

Tags: c#, generics, generic-collections

Recently I got a task to work on one of the FxCop warning - ***Do not expose generic lists***. So I tried changing the `List<T>` to `ICollection<T>`. But later point of time, while doing the unit testing I found that the `AddRange()` is not working properly as expected. It is not adding the collection of elements to the collection object.

Here is the sample code

```
gc.ToList().AddRange(sampleList);
```

And I have two questions to ask

1. Why it is not adding the items to the collection.
   Below is the code:

   ```
   public class GenericClass
   {
       public int Id;
       public string Name;
   }  


   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

         ICollection<GenericClass> gc = new  List<GenericClass>();

       var sampleList = new List<GenericClass>()
                            {
                                new GenericClass {Id = 1, Name = "ASD"},
                                new GenericClass {Id = 2, Name = "QWER"},
                                new GenericClass {Id = 3, Name = "BNMV"},
                            };

       Console.WriteLine(gc.GetType()); // gc is of type

       gc.ToList().AddRange(sampleList); // sampleList items are not getting added to gc.
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   ```

   }
2. `List<T>` inherits from `ICollection<T>` and `List<T>` has `AddRange()`, etc functions. When I tried to cast to parent reference (`ICollection<T>`) to child class object (`List<T>`), why doesn't Intellisense suggest `AddRange()`. Instead I need to do `.ToList()` and then it shows `AddRange()`.
   [image: Screenshot]

I searched a lot for this. But couldn't find a reason that satisfied me. So please help me with the understanding. It will be a great help.

Comment: Change `ICollection<GenericClass>` to `var`. There is no reason to use `ICollection<GenericClass>` in that context.

Comment: `But couldn't find a reason that satisfied me.` You told `gc` that it was a `ICollection`. `ICollection` lacks `AddRange` (it does have `Add` but not `AddRange`). It really is that simple. The solution is to use `var` so that the compiler **knows** that `gc` is a `List`.

Comment: `Do not expose generic lists.` You aren't **exposing** lists anywhere. Unless you are **returning** the list from a function, or declaring a property / field as `List` then you aren't exposing it. 95% of the time in those scenarios (which, again, you aren't in) then you would define the property / field / return type as `IReadOnlyList<T>` It avoids the issues with `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

The `AddRange()` method is working fine. The problem is, you didn't read the documentation for the `ToList()` extension method closely, and so don't realize that the `ToList()` method returns *an entirely new object*.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__):

> Creates a List<T> from an IEnumerable<T>.

Since the object you're calling `AddRange()` with is not in fact the original collection, the original collection remains unchanged.

In a sense, your question is the `List<T>` equivalent to the very common question "why isn't `string.Replace()` working?"

In the example you give, there is not really a much better solution than simply not hiding the `List<T>` in the first place. You can, since you are using the generic `ICollection<T>` interface, write your own `AddRange()` as an extension method:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> range)
{
    foreach (T t in range)
    {
        collection.Add(t);
    }
}
```

But I'm not convinced this is really all that much better than just leaving the type as `List<T>`, if the goal is to be able to modify the object and use an `AddRange()` method.

Casting an `ICollection<T>` reference back to its underlying `List<T>` (as another answerer proposes) is pointless, as doing so would negate any value in using the `ICollection<T>` interface in the first place.

Just leave the reference as `List<T>`, at least in any context where you actually need to modify the collection. (It's fine, and even possibly beneficial, to expose that list in other contexts using only `ICollection<T>`, but that's an entirely different discussion.)

As long as I'm answering, I will mention that I am skeptical that you've correctly understood the intent of the FxCop warning, as exposing generic lists is not in and of itself inherently harmful.

Comment: **ICollection<T> interface doesn't allow modification of the collection at all**. Could you please elaborate on that statement. And can you provide a resolution of how to add items to the collection object then??

Comment: `ICollection<T> interface doesn't allow modification of the collection at all.` That is false. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: ICollection<T> interface doesn't allow modification of the collection at all. But when I am trying to do a ToList().AddRange(simpleList). Why doesn't the list is getting appended to the collection object.   **gc.ToList().AddRange(sampleList);**

Comment: @mjwills: thanks...you won't believe it, but I did in fact look at the docs, was sure there was an Add() method, but couldn't find it, and so wrote what I did. Looks like I got confused about `ICollection` vs `ICollection<T>` (the OP's original post had some formatting issues, and the generic syntax wasn't showing up).

Comment: @Vijay: while I wrote `ICollection<T>` in my statement, what I was actually thinking of was `ICollection`. You can modify `ICollection<T>`...see my edited answer above. As for this: _"Why doesn't the list is getting appended to the collection object"_, I answered that directly in my first paragraph: when you call `AddRange()`, the `this` object the method applies to **is not the `gc` object you started with**. It's the entirely new `List<T>` object that was returned by the `ToList()` method.

Answer (score 2):

`ToList()` returns a new instance, which is why you are not able to see the result of AddRange in "gc". If you really want to use AddRange, you can do the following.

```
((List<GenericClass>)gc).AddRange(sampleList);
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about statement as after I put .ToList() to the object, then only I am see the AddRange function. Is your answer is about question (1) or (2)